# Interpreting Regression Coefficient

Tags: regression, panel-data, linear-model, fixed-effects-model, interpretation

I am using panel data and I have a very simple regression equation of the following form:

$y_{st} = \alpha_s + \beta_t + \gamma F_{st} + \epsilon$

Where, $y_{st}$ is my dependent variable (proportion of infected animal in lab s, at time t), $\gamma$ is the coefficient of interest and $F_{st}$ is a dummy that takes on values $1$ or $0$ to indicate whether a particular treatment was in place or not. When I run this linear model I get a coefficient of $0.23$ which I can interpret right away as follows: ceteris paribus the treatment increases the chances of my dependent variable by $23\%$.

In one of my extensions instead of a $1$ or $0$ dummy I code $F_{st}$ as $0, 1/3, 1/2$ to indicate the levels of treatment ie., instead of using $1$ -- that earlier represented whether treatment was in place or not-- I am indicating the levels of the treatment as $1/3$ or $1/2 or 0%$

When i run this model I get a regression coefficient of $0.623$. I wanted to know how to best interpret this. For instance I know that saying "the treatment increases the chances of my dependent variable by $62.3\%$" is incorrect.

Comment: Questions about the robustness check aside, are you replacing the 1's with nonzero values that are sometimes but not always less than 1, and leaving the zeros as zeros?

Comment: Yes. I am replacing 1s with non-zero values. The treatment is never 100%, so they only take on the values 0(no treatment), 1/3 or 1/2

Comment: What is the dependent variable?  To say "increases the chances of my dependent variable" probably isn't the right language to use in either case.

Comment: My Latin is rather rusty, but I'm remembering that "ceteris" is spelled with an "i" and not a "u". It might be worth checking for future professional communications.

Comment: Yikes! that was a boo-boo! I have corrected it